# Google drive 5 minute quickstart: Error: invalid_client

Tags: php, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run the [example in the quickstart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/quickstart-php)

1. i run the script (I have changed YOUR_CLIENT_ID and YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET in the sample code)
2. i get the url from google to visit to get the validation code
3. i visit the url and  i get `Error: invalid_client`
   I have changed `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` and `YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET` in the sample code.

the response i get is:

> ```
> cookie_policy_enforce=false
> response_type=code
> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
> redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
> access_type=offline
> approval_prompt=force
> client_id=682099869178.project.googleusercontent.com
> ```

any idea what im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the redirect URI to be one of the registered redirect URIs on your [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) project.